# How to solve the "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values" when using optimization toolbox?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement this optimization problem through optimization toolbox:

> [image]

where `N = 60` ﬁles and `K = 130` users when `1/K ≤ M ≤ t∗N/K`, for which `t∗ =3`.
so I wrote this code:

```
 clear all; 
    close all; 
    clc;
    N=60;
    t=3;
    K=130;
    for M=0:0.1:1.4
        r=zeros(size(1:M));
        f=le(1/K,M);
        c=le(M,3*N/K);
        if f || c
        R2 = @(s) -(s-(s./ floor(N./s)).*M);
        LB = 1;
        UB = min(N, K);
        options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point'); % run interior-point algorithm
        [sopt, ropt] = fmincon(R2,1,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options); 
        r(M) = -ropt;
        end 
    end 
    plot(0:1.4,r(M),'r-','LineWidth',2);
    xlabel('Cache Capacity (M)');
    ylabel('Delivery Rate (R)');
```

However the output should be as shown in the graph the one of cut-set bound

> [image]

## The error is as follows:

> Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
>
> Error in try (line 17)
> `r(M) = -ropt`;

Comment: You use `M` as index of `r`, so it should be a positive integer and not a decimal number or zero.

Answer (score 0):

- First define `r` outside of the for loop

```
 r =zeros(size(0:0.1:1.4));
```

- To index r inside the for loop you need integer, M is a float Number.

  you can just define an additional index `i`
- Also you don't need to specify `r` indices while plotting if you want
  to plot the entire array, and remember to keep the abscissa as 
  `0:0.1:1.4`

## The code is as follow

```
N=60;
t=3;
K=130;
i = 0;
r = zeros(size(0:0.1:1.4)); 
for M=0:0.1:1.4
    i = i+1;

    f=le(1/K,M);
    c=le(M,3*N/K);
    if f || c
       R2 = @(s) -(s-(s./ floor(N./s)).*M);
       LB = 1;
       UB = min(N, K);
       options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point'); % run interior-point algorithm
       [sopt, ropt] = fmincon(R2,1,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options); 
       r(i) = -ropt;
     end 

    end 
plot(0:0.1:1.4,r,'r-','LineWidth',2);
xlabel('Cache Capacity (M)');
ylabel('Delivery Rate (R)');
```

---

Alternatively you just can predefine all `M` elements as `M = 0:0.1:1.4`, then loop around using integer index, that can be used also in indexing `r`

## The corresponding code is as follow

```
N=60;
t=3;
K=130;
M = 0:0.1:1.4; 
r = zeros(size(M));

for i = 1:length(M)

    f=le(1/K,M(i));
    c=le(M(i),3*N/K);
    if f || c
        R2 = @(s) -(s-(s./ floor(N./s)).*M(i));
        LB = 1;
        UB = min(N, K);
        options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point'); % run interior-point algorithm
        [sopt, ropt] = fmincon(R2,1,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options); 
        r(i) = -ropt;
    end 

end 
plot(0:0.1:1.4,r,'r-','LineWidth',2);
xlabel('Cache Capacity (M)');
ylabel('Delivery Rate (R)');
```

> ## Graph  [image]